# How to deal with overlapping GameObjects in Unity

Tags: unity

I am making a 2D puzzle game in Unity where puzzle pieces can be joined together.  You join any 2 pieces by first touching one piece and then touching the second piece.

For the purposes of simplifying things a bit, let's assume that:

1. All puzzle pieces are squares.  In other words, there no unique "jigsaw" shapes to worry about... so any puzzle piece can match with any other piece.
2. At the start of the game, the puzzle pieces will be randomly dispersed around the screen, in such a way that none of them overlap.
3. There are 9 total squares, making up a 3x3 large square when solved.
4. Let's say that the total size of the screen is the equivalent of 5x5 squares, so that there's a fair amount of room on the screen for the puzzle pieces to spread out.

Here's how the interface will work:

- As stated, players will touch a first piece and then touch a second piece.
- At that point, the second piece will "teleport" to the right of the first piece.

Here's the challenge: sometimes, 2 freshly-joined pieces will overlap with a third piece lying to the right of the first piece.  The question is, how to handle this?  We could leave the pieces overlapping, but ideally I'd like the pieces to "repel" each other until they are no longer overlapping.

A few notes:

- The most common case is that 2 pieces will repel each other until they are no longer touching.
- A trickier case: if one of the pieces ends up being repelled into a 3rd piece, that 3rd piece can also be repulsed away.
- The trickiest case of all: if any puzzle piece being "repelled" ends up encountering a wall or corner, it can not move any further...  the walls are immovable objects.  In that case, all pieces should be repulsed away from the walls.

Of course, all puzzle pieces are GameObjects and they all will have box colliders.

Any advice on how to configure something like this?  I'm not looking for working code - hoping for general suggestions on possible ways to approach this problem.  Not sure where to start...  any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of teleporting the two touched pieces to each other, move them physically. Any piece inbetween should get pushed out of the way that way. This could even add to the puzzle challenge itself - if you make a hole in the puzzle, the piece cant move there.

Comment: @Zibelas ah clever!  But unfortunately, can't do that here as my puzzle pieces will actually have to match other pieces...  just took that part out of the example here, since it's not directly relevant to the technical side of the problem!

Comment: Presumably you considered using a force-directed graph here? (Effectively weak repelling springs between each pair of un-joined pieces)

Comment: @DMGregory Ah interesting, are there any components or reading I could do to learn more about force-directed graphs?

Comment: My usual first step is to type the words I want to learn about into a search engine, and read the results I get.

Comment: Yes, will definitely do that.  Apologies.

Comment: Update: am trying to use a Point Effector 2D to create a repulsive force!  So far so good... if it works, I'll post more info below.